# Why do my carousel slides just display one under the other?

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

When I hit run or preview in a browser, I am using Chrome, a static view of all three slides stacked 1-3 is displayed.  So they do not toggle through each one.

This is only not working on codeply which I use often.  It does work on codepen and it does work once I add it to my html and CSS files through atom code editor.  Its only codeply that it will not run and I have javascript and bootstrap packages installed in codeply.

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-color: red;">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150" class="d-block w-100" alt="First Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: yellow;">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/ff0000" class="d-block w-100" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: blue;">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x150" class="d-block w-100" alt="Third Slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to provide a full example of the situation.

Comment: As you can see it works fine once the libraries are added. Please revise your post to make it more clear what problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this question.  I wasn't saving my selected framework which was latest bootstrap version in codeply.  It works fine.

Comment: you need to add a propper answer. Like corrected codes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).